# No unit test after upgrade JUNIT 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, junit5

I upgrade my jhipster project from version 5.8.2 to 6.1.0.

Then, I upgrade my classes of unit test follow this link : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-online/issues/107

When I launch :

```
./gradlew test
```

No Unit test was launch ...

Sample of class UnitTest :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static  fr.project.app.web.rest.TestUtil.createFormattingConversionService;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

/**
 * Integration tests for the {@Link WebServiceResource} REST controller.
 */
@SpringBootTest(classes = ProjectApp.class)
public class WebServiceResourceIntTest {
```

There is my build.gradle file :

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
}
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*", "**/*CucumberIT*"
    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }
    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and     https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-repositories - JHipster will add additional     repositories
}

dependencies {
// import JHipster dependencies BOM
    implementation platform("io.github.jhipster:jhipster-    dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}" )

// Use ", version: jhipster_dependencies_version, changing: true" if you want
// to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
implementation group: "io.github.jhipster", name: "jhipster-framework"
....
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude module: "junit"
    exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module: "android-json"
}
testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine"
testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine"
testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core"
testImplementation "junit:junit"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core"
testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library"
testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
//jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional 
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.4.1"
}

...

compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
```

Upgrade jhipster has automatically modify this file

Have you an idea please ?

Comment: What's your gradle config look like?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I edit my post for answer you

Answer (score 1):

I had to add:

```
classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
```

to buildscript dependencies.